# Searching through website for specific URL link?

Tags: url

What is the easiest language or method to input a website's URL and receive every URL on that website for which a given URL is linked. For instance, I would use it if I wanted to see how many times on my website there was a link to a page called oranges.

I would input to the program "http://www.mysite.com" and the URL I wanted to search for "http://www.mysite.com/oranges" and I would run the program. In return I would get a text file or some other file with all of the URLs that contain links to "http://www.mysite.com/oranges".

The input might be:

`http://www.mysite.com http://www.mysite.com/oranges`

And the output might be:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.html
http://www.mysite.com/broccoli.html
http://www.mysite.com/asparagus.html
http://www.mysite.com/fruits.html
http://www.mysite.com/blog/post/my_favorite_fruits.html
```

So far I've tried my personal favorite: Batch, and come up with the following unsuccessful program:

```
FOR /F %%A in (input.txt) DO (
    curl -o temp.html %%A 
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%B in ('FINDSTR /I /R "http://.*" temp.html') DO (
    ECHO %%B >> input.txt
        FOR /F %%C in (temp.html) DO (
            FINDSTR /X "http://.*" %%C >> output.txt
  )         
 )
)
exit
```

It, as stated, doesn't really work.

Any ideas? This is not for a homework assignment, this is for a work project and it's driving me nuts!

Thank you guys in advance for any and all help. Let me know if I need to be more specific about anything!

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, the best you can probably do is an algorithm which grabs the index.html of that url and searches through the HTML for links and a possible sitemap.(Basically creating your own sitemap). There is no guarantee that you will find everything because most developers have stuff hidden for a reason.(Unlinked, etc). You could probably create a recursive method to do what I talked about above.

Comment: I'm confused as to the implementation of what you're talking about. An algorithm how? In Batch? C++? Python? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Are you asking how to program it? In that case Jon's answer is essentially correct. (And it could be coded in almost any language including C++, Python, Delphi, Java, C# or whatever.) If you are looking for an existing program to scan your website and tell you where any given URL is linked from, you can try tools like "XENU", "A1 Website Analyzer" and similar.

Comment: As Tom pointed out there are plenty of tools out there that you can probably get the best results from. One way that might be feasible is to have a search engine do it for you. You can go to google/bing/yahoo and use their site: tag to search each site. EX type in Google (site:http://www.cnn.com) NO PARENS and add the appropriate http:// and www. this will give you all the pages that google has found for the site. You can probably write something that just scrapes all of the search result urls for the site URL you give.

Answer (score 1):

Try Scrapy http://scrapy.org/. It is a python framework that helps crawl html content from start urls and scrape them.

It also recursively crawls the scraped links and has best algorithms to not duplicate crawled urls.
The document is easy to follow and create a simple program.